# How to convert UTC to another timezone in MongoDB with NestJs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, timezone, nestjs, moment-timezone

We have a requirement of converting a date received in UTC time zone to EST or CST etc;
So we receive a serires of events with a dateTime in UTC. We would need to loop the events and perform some calculations at midnight depending upon the time zone at midnight.
We get all the list of events for a specific timezone and perform some calculations. I am trying to figure out the best possible way to do this. We have mongodb and NestJS with mongoose library.
I tried converting the UTC to EST or whatever timezone using `date-fns-tz` library and even tried with `moment` the output is a date in string while we have the eventDateTime as Date type and this saves the date as UTC not EST.
1)It is better to save the eventDateTime by converting it to a specific timezone and perform the calculations?
2)Or anything else.
Please advise.

So here is the sample json I have and collection let's say `eventsCollection`

``

```
{
 "code": "DRL-0014",    
 "status": "Training",
 "sourceSystem": "sourceSystem",
 "traineeCode":"EMP4510",
 "eventCode": "EVT-1012",
 "eventDateTime": "2023-08-16T02:00:00.000Z",
 "remark": "remark",
 "clock": { 
   "timeRemaining": 21600
 },   
},
{
 "code": "DRL-0014",    
 "status": "Training",
 "sourceSystem": "sourceSystem",
 "traineeCode":"EMP4510",
 "eventCode": "EVT-1012",
 "eventDateTime": "2023-08-16T03:00:00.000Z",
 "remark": "remark",
 "clock": { 
   "timeRemaining": 18000
 },   
},
```

``

So, we will have a series of events and we need to rely on the timezone to calculate a series of events that occurred in 24 hours cycle. So, we calculate them from midnight until midnight(24 hours) and save as single document and since there is a gap of 4 hours b/w utc and est and 5 hours between utc which means few events may fall in another day if we rely on utc for the calculations so we need to convert the eventDateTime to EST or CST or whatever timezone saved in our different collection and have inserted in `eventsCollection` collection with a new field called `startDateTime`. So, `"eventDateTime": "2023-08-16T03:00:00.000Z",` conversion of EST will be `"eventDateTime": "2023-08-15T23:00:00-04:00",` or simply `2023-08-15T23:00:00`. Also, we will be having thousands of documents to calculate every midnight for almost many timezones. The converted documents looks like below with an additional field
``

```
{
 "code": "DRL-0014",    
 "status": "Training",
 "sourceSystem": "sourceSystem",
 "traineeCode":"EMP4510",
 "eventCode": "EVT-1012",
 "eventDateTime": "2023-08-16T02:00:00.000Z",
 "shiftStartDateTime": "2023-08-15T22:00:00.000",
 "remark": "remark",
 "clock": { 
   "timeRemaining": 21600
 },   
},
{
 "code": "DRL-0014",    
 "status": "Training",
 "sourceSystem": "sourceSystem",
 "traineeCode":"EMP4510",
 "eventCode": "EVT-1012",
 "eventDateTime": "2023-08-16T03:00:00.000Z",
 "shiftStartDateTime": "2023-08-15T23:00:00.000",
 "remark": "remark",
 "clock": { 
   "timeRemaining": 18000
 },   
},
```

``
Also, the job which runs once will calculate based on the `shiftStartDateTime` will save the result in another collection for each "traineeCode"

``

```
{
 "code": "DRL-0014",    
 "status": "Training",
 "traineeCode":"EMP4510",
 "eventCode": "EVT-1012",
 "shiftStartDateTime": "2023-08-15T22:00:00.000",
 "remark": "remark",
 "totalTime:"18000" // Since 21600-3600=18000(which is 5 hours)
},
{
 "code": "DRL-0015",    
 "status": "Training",
 "traineeCode":"EMP4511",
 "eventCode": "EVT-4012",
 //....
},
...and so on
```

``
In javascript I tried doing something like
`const estTimestamp = moment(event.eventDateTime).tz('America/New_York').toDate();`

Comment: Without valid sample data it is difficult to understand your question. In general MongoDB stores UTC times - **always and only**. Timezones and output formats are usually handled by the client application. You can query also with different timezone, e.g. `{$match: {eventDateTime: {$gt: ISODate('2023-08-18T11:00:00+02:00') }}}`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit thanks for the advise this will help me, I have added some more context can you please advise.

Comment: Do you store the values as string? You should **never** do that, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects. Perhaps it's just the way how your editor formats the output - in this case ignore my statement. Otherwise queries like `{$match: {eventDateTime: {$gt: estTimestamp  }}}` should work.